# Angular: delete image from assets

Tags: angular

Is it possible to delete images from assets by code?

I want to delete files from assets since i save them there once the add operation is done successfully, so if a user deletes a record which has a linked image stored in assets, i want to remove it by code but i don't know how.

Something like this:

```
          this.records
            .deletet(id)
            .pipe()
            .subscribe(data => {
              if(data ==="Success"){
               // delete from assets too
              }
            });
```

Comment: not possible without using a web service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the content will be converted into a bundle when you build the app, it is not possible to delete the contents of the assets from the bundle through angular.

But, you can still achieve what you want by performing file operations where your bundle is located. Usually angular stores the assets inside the bundle in following path **public/assets/images** . So you can delete the content from there using other libraries which was not recommended because your app may crash, if not handled properly.